# How to make EntityFramework add rows in order?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my SQL Server database I use autoincrementing field for Id. Whenever I add new rows to that table with SQL Server entity I want those IDs to keep order of adding those rows in Entity Framework - but for some reason it is random.

Answer (score 3):

Call `SaveChanges()` after each `AddObject`. That's the only way to control the order.